# Error on simple html dom removing elements

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using simple html dom. I hav this code:

```
<html>
<div class="one">
<div class="two">this is inner text </div>
<a href="#" class="three">this is inner anchor</a>
This is outer test
</div>
</html>
```

I want to fetch `This is outer test` only.
Here is my code :

```
$html = file_get_html(SITE_URL.'/forumlist.php');  
$html->find('.two',0)->outertext = "";
$html->find('.three',0)->outertext = "";
$html->save();
echo $html->find('.one',0)->plaintext;
```

and I got disappointed..

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: i am getting everything .. 'this is inner text this is inner anchor This is outer test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I read the documentation, I don't think you can get that out as easy as you imagine ( I might be wrong of course ), but you can just remove the unneeded strings manually with `str_replace`:

```
$string = '<html>
<div class="one">
<div class="two">this is inner text </div>
<a href="#" class="three">this is inner anchor</a>
This is outer test
</div>
</html>';

$html = str_get_html( $string );
echo str_replace(
        array(
            $html->find('.two',0)->plaintext,
            $html->find('.three',0)->plaintext
        ),
        null,
        $html->find('.one',0)->plaintext
    );
```

This should actually do the trick, if you know the structure of the html.